# MSMTP on Monterey: msmtp: no recipients found

Tags: macos, email, gmail, open-source

I have MSMTP running flawlessly on four Raspberry Pies. I use it to send email from shell scripts. It works fine as a SMTP client.

I installed MSMTP and mailutils on an M1 iMac via MacPorts.

I configured MSMTP as follows using the information here: [msmtp_gmail_setup](https://github.com/okovko/msmtp_gmail_setup/blob/master/msmtp_setup.sh)

/etc/mail.rc:

```
set append dot save ask crt
ignore Received Message-Id Resent-Message-Id Status Mail-From Return-Path Via
set sendmail=/opt/local/bin/msmtp
```

The only thing I added was the "set sendmail" line.

.msmtprc looks like this:

```
# Generics
defaults
auth           on
tls            on
# tls_starttls   on
# following is different from ssmtp:
# tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
# user specific log location, otherwise use /var/log/msmtp.log, however,
# this will create an access violation if you are user pi, and have not changes the access
rights

tls_fingerprint 7D:8B:CD:37<snip>

logfile  ~/.msmtp.log

# my  specifics
account        gmail
auth           plain
host           smtp.gmail.com
port           587
from           me@gmail.com
user           me
password       my_password

# Default
account default : gmail
```

If I run the mail command on the command line it lets me address and compose a message, but I get the following error:

```
msmtp: no recipients found
Sending data to /opt/local/bin/msmtp failed: Process exited with a non-zero status
cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

There are no entries in  ~/.msmtp.log

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Most likely there is no `/home/pi` on your Mac, so the path to the log file for sure is wrong. Also, if you use the same `.msmtprc` on the Pi, does it work there?

Comment: Thank you. That was a silly mistake, wasn’t it. And, yes that very same .msmtprc runs fine on the Pi except that it uses  a tls trust file instead of a tls fingerprint.

Comment: I changed the OP to reflect changes I made in .msmtprc. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work and nothing gets posted to the log file. Probably another silly error somewhere.

Comment: With hindsight most mistakes are silly :-)

Comment: Well, I must have made at least one more because I still can't get it to work :-{

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that after I installed msmtp and mailutils I ended up with two versions of the mail binary:

```
Valentine:~ mnewman$ which -a mail
/opt/local/bin/mail
/usr/bin/mail
```

msmtp works with /usr/bin/mail but not with /opt/local/bin/mail (the one installed by mailutils). I have no idea why this is the case.

```
Valentine:~ mnewman$ /opt/local/bin/mail me@mac.com
Cc:
Subject: none
test
msmtp: no recipients found
Sending data to /opt/local/bin/msmtp failed: Process exited with a non-zero status
cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

The above clearly fails. That below succeeds.

```
Valentine:~ mnewman$ /usr/bin/mail me@mac.com
Subject: none
test
EOT
```

I solved the problem, at least for the command line, by creating an alias pointing to the version that doesn't fail. In shell scripts I use the full path for most binaries, so that won't be a problem

Comment: Don't use full paths in your shell scripts; set up a sane `PATH`